# How to Check Bluetooth ON/OFF in iOS 11+ in swift

Tags: swift4, react-native-ios

Here is my Code!

I Have 
iOS 11+,
swift 4+,
CoreBluetooth Framework

while I'm running my application it always shows Bluetooth is Off.but I run the same code in below iOS 10 version its runs how its happening?

My priority is to run on iOS 11+ what should I do? any suggestion???

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController,CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    var manager: CBCentralManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch (central.state) {
        case .poweredOn:
            print("bluetooth Powered ON")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("bluetooth Powered OFF")
        case .unsupported:
            print("bltyh noit supported")
        case .unknown:
            print("bltyh noit unknown")
        case .resetting:
            print("bltyh noit resetting")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("bltyh noit unauthorized")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300632/check-bluetooth-status-swift-4

Comment: yeah its working on iOS 9 but its deprecated in iOS 11+,@available(iOS, introduced: 5.0, deprecated: 10.0, message: "Use CBManagerState instead")

Comment: Here is a quote from the Apple Docs. "Before you call CBCentralManager methods, the state of the central manager object must be powered on, as indicated by the poweredOn constant. This state indicates that the central device (your iPhone or iPad, for instance) supports Bluetooth low energy and that Bluetooth is on and available to use."

Comment: I not getting you..can you provide code snippet