# How to store Bluetooth Status in a variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I have implemented CBManagerDelegate and can print the status successfully, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300632/check-bluetooth-status-swift-4) . **But** I want to store this state in a variable and use in my post API. How to proceed?

Tried to store in a variable normally but failed. Protocols might work but I am not sure.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    
    var isBTTurnedOn: Bool?
    var manager: CBCentralManager!

    public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    
        switch central.state {
          case .poweredOn:
            print("Bluetooth is ON.")
            isBTTurnedOn = true
              break
          case .poweredOff:
              print("Bluetooth is Off.")
            isBTTurnedOn = false
            
        @unknown default:
             break
        }
        
    }
    
 //IN THE VIEWDIDLOAD() -> 
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = CBCentralManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        }

// IN VIEWWILLAPPEAR()

print("Bt status is \(isBTTurnedOn)")) // Getting nil here
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried? Can you clarify exactly what you want to do? Do you want to call an api when you receive data from a Bluetooth device?

Comment: Edited and added the code in question. I have also tried computed property for isBTTurnedOn but with no luck!

Comment: `viewWillAppear` will run before the Bluetooth state is determined. You can use a `didSet` in your property or a closure or notification Center or combine

Comment: Can you show an example using didSet please?

Comment: Basically `var isBTTurnedOn: Bool? { didSet { if let btOn = isBTTurnedOn { // do something with the value } }`

Comment: You probably don’t actually want it in a single variable, because the Bluetooth status isn’t static. It can change at any point, and you’ll probably want you app to respond to that. That’s why the ask doesn’t give you a simple “is Bluetooth on?” boolean property to check. They aren’t making you jump through hoops for fun. This delegate callback exists precisely for you to be able to keep your app up-to-date with the latest Bluetooth status as soon it changes. Delegates can be a bit clunky to work with, but that’s where things like Combine come in.

Comment: As you have a central manager var, you can just read its state : manager.state and use it in a computed bool var.

Comment: manager.state.rawValue always returns 0, that is bluetooth status is unknown. 

From documentation - @discussion The current state of the manager, initially set to <code>CBManagerStateUnknown</code>.
     *    Updates are provided by required delegate method {@link managerDidUpdateState:}.